# Convert string of floats to list of rounded floats

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column from string to float. The df column looks something like below. Some rows have no numbers in them, but are a space ' '.

```
    col
'1.1, 1.0006'
    '  '
```

I am trying to round each number to the third decimal place. The output would look something like this.

```
    col
'1.100, 1.001'
    '  '
```

My thinking:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)
df['col'] = df['col'].round(3)
```

Comment: Did you try doing as your thinking?

Comment: Sorry I will update the question. I get the following error: could not convert string to float: '1.1, 1.0006'

Comment: `df = df.astype({"col": float})` ?

Comment: This gives me the error: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':["'1.1, 1.0006'", "'   '"]})
print (df)

def func(x):
    out = []
    #split and strip values, try convert each value to float, if error, get original value
    for y in x.strip("'").split(', '):
        try:
            out.append(round(float(y), 3))
        except:
            out.append(y)

    return (out)

df['new'] = df['col'].apply(func)
print (df)
             col           new
0  '1.1, 1.0006'  [1.1, 1.001]
1          '   '         [   ]
```

If need strings from floats use `f-strings`:

```
def func(x):
    out = []
    for y in x.strip("'").split(', '):
        try:
            out.append(f'{round(float(y), 3):.3f}')
        except:
            out.append(y)

    return (out)

df['new'] = df['col'].apply(func)
print (df)

             col             new
0  '1.1, 1.0006'  [1.100, 1.001]
1          '   '           [   ]
```

And for strings add `join` to end:

```
def func(x):
    out = []
    for y in x.strip("'").split(', '):
        try:
            out.append(f'{round(float(y), 3):.3f}')
        except:
            out.append(y)

    return (', '.join(out))

df['new'] = df['col'].apply(func)
print (df)
             col           new
0  '1.1, 1.0006'  1.100, 1.001
1          '   '
```

Comment: The Jon Skeet of pandas strikes.

Comment: Both solutions give me the same error: 'could not convert string to float: '

Comment: @MaxB - Can you check changed solution with sample data?

Comment: @jezrael the new solution gives me the same error :(

Comment: @MaxB - So problem with sample data, different like in your question. Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Or better there is possible some non float value like `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':["'1.1, 1.0006'","'aaa, 1.25'"]})` ?

Comment: @jezrael there are several rows that do not have any information in them. This is where the issue is. I will update the question to reflect.

Comment: @MaxB - Can you check now?

Comment: @jezrael it does not throw any errors, however the numbers do not seem to round still.

Comment: So it seems data related problem, what is `print (df['col'].head(10).tolist())` ?

Comment: It works now. I was looking at the old column, not the new one. My apologies. Thank you for the help!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try this:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))
def string_to_float(list):
    x = []
    for each in list:
        x.append(round(float(each), 3))
    return x
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: string_to_float(x))
```

**UPDATE:**
The following code will work perfectly now:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("'", "").replace(" ", "").split(','))
def string_to_float(list):
    x = []
    for each in list:
        if each != '':
            x.append((str(round(float(each), 3))))
    return ','.join(x)
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: string_to_float(x))
```

Comment: This also gives me the error: 'could not convert string to float: ' I think this is caused by the rows that are blank (actually a string that is one space -->  ' ')

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def fix_string(string):
    numbers = pd.to_numeric(string.split(','), errors='coerce').round(3)
    return numbers

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(fix_string)
```

Comment: This doesn't give me any errors but for some reason doesn't seem to round the numbers.

Comment: @MaxB did you assign  it back to `df`? ie `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(fix_string)`